Calculate the usefulness of keeping water warm
I hope this is appropriate for this stack.
I have an electric water kettle which can keep the water warm.
I would like to calculate when it makes sense to keep it warm in contrast to reheating it depending on the amount of water and I suppose room temperature.
According to the manual it takes $27$ minutes to heat water to $100 \ ^\circ \text{C}$ from $23 \ ^\circ \text{C}$ with a room temperature of $23 \ ^\circ \text{C}$ as well.
Additionally it mentions that it would take $30$ minutes to drop that temperature to $90 \ ^\circ \text{C}$ in the kettle, $1 \ \text{hour} \ 20 \ \text{minutes}$ for $80 \ ^\circ \text{C}$ and $2 \ \text{hours} \ 10 \ \text{minutes}$ for $70 \ ^\circ \text{C}$.
There is unfortunately no description how the keep warm function works in detail.
The device has $700 \ \text{W}$ at $100 \ \text{V}$, $50-60 \ \text{Hz}$.
How do I calculate when it makes sense do keep warm or reheat?
Thank you!

If the temperature of the water drops it will lose less heat. This means the heat lost over a time period will be greater if the temperature is maintained, so the energy used will also be greater. However the power consumed will be less while it is maintaining its temperature than  while it is heating up. What "makes sense" depends on what is needed in the specific situation.

If you are wondering which option will save the most energy, it is always most efficient to let the water cool and then reheat it. The water will lose heat at a rate proportional to its own temperature, so that as it cools it loses energy more slowly. As you're "keeping it warm" it loses energy at the fastest rate.
If this question is about wasting time, you'll need to come up with a way to quantify how much convenience matters.

So you are basically saying there is no scenario where keeping the water at temperature at level makes more sense than letting it cool down and then reheating it back to the desired level.
But how can we prove it?
It's not about wasting time. It is just a press of a button. Or no press at all if you keep it warm, as the kettle does this by default after boiling.

you wrote: "it is always most efficient to let the water cool and then reheat it". Do you have a formal for this?

@hyportnex Newton's law of cooling says heat lost per unit time is $\frac{dU}{dt} = -\tau \Delta T$, where $\tau$ is a constant and $\Delta T$ is the difference in temperature between the two reservoirs. The closer the hot water is to room temperature the less heat gets lost.

Let me rephrase my question more precisely. Given a body and its $C_p=C_p(T)$ heat capacity, the body loses heat per Newton's law to its environment that is at $T_1$. We wish to maintain the body's temperature at $T_2 \pm \delta T$ where $T_1 = T_2  - \Delta T_1$ and $T_1, T_2, \delta T \ll  \Delta T_1$ are given. What is the optimum heating strategy that minimizes the average power consumption of the heater?
